# Reflection...NPE when getting field value

Tags: java, spring, reflection

I have this POJO class :

```
  @Component
  public class ClassOne{
    public int  id;
    public String fname;
    public String lname;
    public String    code;

    super constructor
    fields constructor
    getters & setters
   }
```

I have this service class :

```
   @Service
   public  class ClassOneServiceImpl implements ClassOneService{

  public ClassOneServiceImpl{}

  @override
  public boolean addUser(String fname,String lname,String code){

    Class<?> theClass = 
    Class.forName("com.somepackage.ClassOne");
    Constructor<?> theClassConstructor = 
   theClass.getConstructor(String.class, String.class,String.class);
    ClassOne theClassObj = (ClassOne) 
   theClassConstructor.newInstance("fname","lname","code");

    Field fnameField = theClass.getDeclaredField("fname");
    Field lnameField = theClass.getDeclaredField("lname");
    Field codeField = theClass.getDeclaredField("code");

    System.out.println("Field name is " + 
    fnameField.getName());  //I get the Field's name

String fnameStr =(String) 
       fnameField.get(theClassObj);  //the NPE caused here 
String lnameStr =(String) 
       lnameField.get(theClassObj);


    System.out.println(fnameStr);  //here getting null

    ...here is the code to persist the form's field data .

  }

}
```

Obviously the "theClassObj" is not been instantiated,since the service class has no main method ...
What's my mistake & how to get the instance in this case ?

I tried place the instance from within the service class constructor..didn't work.

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

Comment: Why you want to use reflection?

Comment: Theclassobj is instantiated, because you do it by calling newInstance. How can you get an output if an exception is thrown?

Comment: When testing the code I do not get an NPE. Anyway some parts of the question make no sense to me. What is the supposed relation of the object instantion and the main method of some other class? As `Yuvaraj Shanmugam` pointed out the comments are not matching the behaviour of the API. And `fnameString` does not exist, maybe you wanted to refer to `fnameStr`. You should update the question and add an explanation of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Jens ..it's either the "fnameField" is null Or "theClassObj" is null ..I assumed the the latter is null , since the   fnameField.getName() is giving me a result .

Comment: @second..yes it's "fnameStr" . I want persist  the fields values of a form into DB , this time I want do this using reflection .From some readings about reflection I think will enhance the persistence performance !    will it ?

Comment: Do you have some source for this assumption?

Comment: Creating the newInstance should probably look like this as well `theClassConstructor.newInstance(fname,lname,code);` so you actually supply the parameters from your method.

Comment: @second ... No,as I said I'm trying this.But I still need to know what caused the NPE  , though I agree with you that newInstance() should gets me an instance.The NPE  should be thrown if instance fields is in the class & null as argument.

Comment: @second...I tried your suggestion using the parameters ..it didn't work either ...I still think the new instance for some reason is not initialized !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194596/discussion-between-second-and-mohd).

Comment: @second ...Thanks for your time . I found my mistake I was doing which was giving me the NPE exception...dumb mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment line, you are saying '`fnameField`' is null.

This is not possible. Because "`fnameField`" can not be null. Following statement would give you either `Field` object or `NoSuchFieldException`.

```
Field fnameField = theClass.getDeclaredField("fname");
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
I replace the answer as you seem to have figured out something, so I am still not sure that this was really the problem.

Based on your answer, your real problem might be that you allow a value of 'null' for userId, email and/or password. In this case all your code needs are some not null checks.

Your answer points in a direction that now instead of having a null value to test against, you just test a String `"null"` instead.

```
useridString =(String) useridField.get(signupClassObj);
System.out.println(useridString);
emailString = (String)emailField.get(signupClassObj);
passwordString = (String)passwordField.get(signupClassObj);

... check if values are not null ...

if (!useridString.isEmpty() && !emailString.isEmpty() && !passwordString.isEmpty()) {
```

Answer (score 0):

ok the NPE I was getting it's because I was wrapping the Field object to a String in a what seems a wrong way :
String fnameStr =(String) fnameField.get(theClassObj);  //the NPE caused here

to wrapp correctly :
String fnameStr =String.valueOf(fnameField.get(theClassObj));

the NPE now gone .
Thanks .

Comment: Last time we talked you pointed out that the NPE is thrown by an if statement below the code you had posted. Based on the resolution I assume you try to set a null value into one of your fields. Be mindfull that now you might have end up with a String ```"null"``` instead of what you actually want to have (a null value).

Comment: I`ve replaced my previous answer with a new one. You should be able to debug it easily to figure out if that is a problem you are having now. (I haven't heard that casting a null value would acutally cause a NPE)